# Symfony2 and production environment - allways displays app_dev in links

Tags: symfony, nginx, production-environment

I have a symfony2 project running with nginx and the problem is that when accessing the prod environment, all the links are still with app_dev.php there.

Here are my config files:

**app.php**

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel->handle(Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
```

The links in the twig file are called this way:

Route name: user_login, in twig: user_login_path()

Where could the problem come from? Nginx?

Comment: Do you mean `/app.php` redirects to `/app_dev.php` ? You may have some bad rewrite in a `.htaccess` or something ?

Comment: No, for example I open my page with app.php, everything is there except that all the href links on tha page are with app_dev.php on them.

Comment: Ok... Do you use `path('route_name')` for the links href ?

Comment: No, I am using for example for the "user_login" route: user_login_path()

Comment: You should edit your question with this but with more details.

Comment: What is user_login_path() ?

Comment: Done, any idea why this is happening? On another server everything works well.

Comment: I don't know, 'cause I always use `<a href="{{ path('routename') }}">link</a>` for my links... Where does the `user_login_path()` comes from ? Please give an example of a template

Comment: I have no Idea, it is an old code I am running. It seems that this is a macro or something: example: `<a href="{{ user_login_path() }}">Login</a>`

Comment: Try with `<a href="{{ path('user_login') }}">login</a>`... I think this "macro" is bad coded. It does not come from Symfony itself

Comment: Right, it works perfectly fine using the path from twig. Hm, how to find now this macro, or whatever it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `path('route_name')` in order to generate links or actions. It seems that the function(s) you are using (kind of twig extension) is bad coded and server dependent. But it does not comes with Symfony itself.

You have multiple options :

- The cleanest : replace every `href`, `action`, ... with the `path` function
- A (maybe) faster one : find the custom twig extension and make it work (more likely in `src/Acme/MyBundle/Twig/MyExtension.php`)
- A quick and dirty one : rewrite every `app_dev.php` urls to `app.dev` with a `.htaccess` (not really recommended at all but... well...)